# Change field value with JavaScript onChange Function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to change the `quota-adesao` value, which is the value of `quota-entrada` decided by the value of `quota-parcelas`

**JavaScript**

```
adesao = 0.00;
entrada = document.getElementById('quota-entrada');
parcelas = document.getElementById('quota-parcelas');
var adesaoResult = document.getElementById('quota-adesao');


const totalAdesao = document.querySelectorAll('.quota-row');
totalAdesao.forEach(entrada => {

    var index = entrada.getAttribute('data-index');
    var entrada = document.getElementById(`quota-entrada-${index}`);
    var parcelas = document.getElementById(`quota-parcelas-${index}`);
    //parseFloat(entrada);

    adesao = parseFloat(entrada.value) / parcelas;

})

adesaoResult.value = adesao;
```

***HTML***

I'm using onchange to do the `quota-adesao` calculation, when the `quota-parcelas` is inserted the `quota-adesao`is automatically filled

```html
<div class="row quota-row" data-index="0">

  <div class="col-8" id="quota-principal">

    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span>Entrada 1</span>
        <input type="text" onblur="calculaRestante(this)" data-index="0" id="quota-entrada-0" required="" name="entrada[]" placeholder="Primeira Parte" id="valor8" value="0">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2 dateInput">
        <span>Forma de Pagamento</span>
        <select onchange="onChangeFormaPagamento(this)" data-index="0" id="quota-forma-pagamento-0" name="forma_pagamento[]">

          <option value="">Selecione a forma de pagamento</option>

          <?php foreach ($formas_pagamentos as $forma_pagamento) { ?>

          <option value="<?= $forma_pagamento->id_formas_pagamento ?>">
            <?= $forma_pagamento->forma_pagamento ?>
          </option>

          <?php } ?>

        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-1 dateInput">
        <span>Parcelas</span>
        <select data-index="0" id="quota-parcelas-0" name="parcelas[]" onchange="calculaAdesao()">
          <option value=""></option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span>Vencimento</span>

        <input data-index="0" id="quota-vencimento-0" type="date" required="" name="vencimento[]" placeholder="Entrada">

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span>Adesão</span>
        <input data-index="0" id="quota-adesao-0" type="text" required="" name="adesao[]" placeholder="Valor de entrada">
        <!-- id="valor6" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you maybe provide the frontend part without the php tags? Just put some dummy code there. It makes it easier to find a solution to your problem!

Comment: Hello I managed to solve part of the problem, as follows the answer

Comment: I see. Is it correct that within `<div class="row quota-row" data-index="0">` there are multiple instances of `<div class="col-8" id="quota-principal">`? And within each of these `quota-principal` you have to calculate a different value?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the calculation with the following code, but I still need to calculate the other "quota-adesao" that you saw in the index. The code is only doing the calculation for the index - 0

```
function calculaAdesao() {

adesao = 0.00;
//entrada = document.getElementById('quota-entrada');
//parcelas = document.getElementById('quota-parcelas');
var adesaoResult = document.getElementById('quota-adesao');


const totalAdesao = document.querySelectorAll('.quota-row');
totalAdesao.forEach(entrada => {

    var index = entrada.getAttribute('data-index');
    var entrada = document.getElementById(`quota-entrada-${index}`);
    var parcelas = document.getElementById(`quota-parcelas-${index}`);
    var adesaoTest = document.getElementById(`quota-adesao-${index}`);
    //parseFloat(entrada);

    adesao = parseFloat(entrada.value) / parcelas.value;

    adesaoTest.value = adesao;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

as I could not quite understand how you want to implement the code and the functions I have made the following assumptions:
First I assumed that a user would be able to insert multiple "Entrada's". Your code would then look, in the base, like this:

```html
<div class="row quota-row">
    <h3>First</h3>
    <div class="col-8 quota-principal" data-index="0">
       ...Entrada
    </div>

    <h3>Second</h3>
    <div class="col-8 quota-principal" data-index="1">
       ...Entrada
    </div>
</div>
```

This way, you could loop through each entrada by selecting it with  `document.querySelectorAll('.quota-principal')`. Each of these elements has the attribute `data-index` which gives you a number like `0,1,2` etc. With that number you can then get the items with an `id` like `<input type="text" id="quota-entrada-0" ... />` which wasn't possible with the by you provide code.

Now you can properly select and set the `adesaoTest` element within each `quota-principal`.

The full working example can be found below.

```js
function calculaAdesao() {
    adesao = 0.00;

    const totalAdesao = document.querySelectorAll('.quota-principal');
    totalAdesao.forEach(entrada => {
      var index = entrada.getAttribute('data-index');
      var entrada = document.getElementById(`quota-entrada-${index}`);
      var parcelas = document.getElementById(`quota-parcelas-${index}`);
      let adesaoTest = document.getElementById(`quota-adesao-${index}`);
      adesao = parseFloat(entrada.value) / parcelas.value;
      adesaoTest.value = isNaN(adesao) ? "" : adesao;

    })
  }

  function calculaRestante(l) {}

  function onChangeFormaPagamento(l) {}
```

```html
  <div class="row quota-row">
    <h3>First</h3>
    <div class="col-8 quota-principal" data-index="0">

      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Entrada 1</span>
          <input type="text" onblur="calculaRestante(this); calculaAdesao()" id="quota-entrada-0" required="" name="entrada[]" placeholder="Primeira Parte" id="valor8" value="0">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 dateInput">
          <span>Forma de Pagamento</span>
          <select onchange="onChangeFormaPagamento(this)" id="quota-forma-pagamento-0" name="forma_pagamento[]">
            <option value="">Selecione a forma de pagamento</option>
            <option value="card">cartão
            <option value="dinheiro">dinheiro
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 dateInput">
          <span>Parcelas</span>
          <select data-index="0" id="quota-parcelas-0" name="parcelas[]" onchange="calculaAdesao()">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>

          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Vencimento</span>
          <input id="quota-vencimento-0" type="date" required="" name="vencimento[]" placeholder="Entrada">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Adesão</span>
          <input id="quota-adesao-0" type="text" required="" name="adesao[]" placeholder="Valor de entrada">
          <!-- id="valor6" -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3>Second</h3>
    <div class="col-8 quota-principal" data-index="1">

      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Entrada 1</span>
          <input type="text" onblur="calculaRestante(this); calculaAdesao()" id="quota-entrada-1" required="" name="entrada[]" placeholder="Primeira Parte" value="0">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 dateInput">
          <span>Forma de Pagamento</span>
          <select onchange="onChangeFormaPagamento(this)" id="quota-forma-pagamento-1" name="forma_pagamento[]">
            <option value="">Selecione a forma de pagamento</option>
            <option value="card">cartão
            <option value="dinheiro">dinheiro
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-1 dateInput">
          <span>Parcelas</span>
          <select id="quota-parcelas-1" name="parcelas[]" onchange="calculaAdesao()">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>

          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Vencimento</span>
          <input id="quota-vencimento-1" type="date" required="" name="vencimento[]" placeholder="Entrada">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <span>Adesão</span>
          <input id="quota-adesao-1" type="text" required="" name="adesao[]" placeholder="Valor de entrada" value="">
          <!-- id="valor6" -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this can be of any help, if not please comment!

Comment: Thank you very much friend your answer serve me a lot. But I found the problem without looking for that it sent the data of the second element. The error is because within the id that seeks the element "quota-adesao" it had space and generated conflict in the search for the ID

Comment: excellent answer, the problem was less than I imagined

Comment: Great to hear! Did, in the end, help you?

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with JavaScript and want to learn more